# Use "Additional Include Directories" of referenced project in Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am currently implementing a C++ static library for a large software codebase that is still using Visual Studio Solutions. I have created my library using CMake. The library contains a single external header and multiple internal static libraries.

Building the new library by itself works perfectly fine, but as soon as I try to include the external header of the library in the main project and build it, the Visual Studio Solution project is complaining that the path to the internal headers of the new proejct are not correct.

Is there any way to propagate the additional include directories from referenced projects in Visual Studio Solutions, or is my approach to the integration completely off to begin with? It feels a bit redundant to have to add all Additional Include Directories of EVERY referenced project in the main project, all over again.

Comment: You mean that your solution has 2 project and library project is OK, but solution has problem, don`t you?

Comment: What I mean is that the project that is generated by CMake works perfectly fine to build on its own in Visual Studio, but as soon as I include the external header of that project in the main project, the headers that the external header includes are not found, i.e. I have to add the Additional Include Directories a second time in the main project, which feels very redundant.

Comment: To clarify: Are you trying to solve this problem in CMake or in Visual Studio? That is, do you want CMake to generate a solution file that does not have this problem, or are you working with a pre-generated solution file and you are looking for the right Visual Studio option to make it work?

Comment: @ComicSansMS At the moment I am stuck with an already existing pre-generated solution file, no CMake for the main project exists yet, so I am trying to solve the problem in Visual Studio. The simple, but kind of annoying solution is to simply copy all Additional Include Directories from the CMake generated project to the main project, but I am wondering if there are any options to simply propagate them "automatically".

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to do this. The best approach I can think of is have your CMake project produce a [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/) package which is then consumed by the VS solution project. But static libraries don't isolate you from the downstream dependencies at all, so you will still have to wrap the headers *and* library files for all of those as part of the package. If true isolation is desired, you actually need to change the code of your library to enable this, by wrapping away all functions and types from the downstream libraries and link it as a dll instead of static lib.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I was afraid that was the case. I cannot wait for the codebase to migrate to CMake, so much easier to work with. Thank you for your answer. Do you mind posting your comment to the post, and I will mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of an easy way to do this.

The best approach I can think of is have your CMake project produce a [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/) package which is then consumed by the VS solution project.

But static libraries don't isolate you from the downstream dependencies at all. You will still need to include all the header files and `.lib` files from your dependencies to be part of the package for this to work. If true isolation is desired, you actually need to change the code of your library to enable this - by wrapping away all functions and types from the downstream libraries and link your library as a shared library (`.dll`) instead of building it to a static library.